# Create/Update static block programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, static-block, recurring

I am trying to create/update static block programmatically with recurringData.php from setup script.

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
class RecurringData implements InstallDataInterface
{

protected $storeManager;    
protected $_objectManager;
private  $blockFactory;
protected $_urlInterface;
protected $state;   

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,       
    BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->_urlInterface    = $urlInterface;
    $this->state = $state;
}

  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
  $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
   $customBlock= $this->blockFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load('test-block', 'identifier');
      $objectManager  = $this->_objectManager;   
       $media_dir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
         ->getStore()
         ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                $Image = $media_dir."test.png";

                $contentBlock = [ 
                    'title' => 'Test Block',
                    'identifier' => 'test-block',
                    'stores' => $storeId,
                    'is_active' => 1,
                    'content' => '<div class="test-update">
                                    <h3>Static Block</h3>
                                    <div class="update-options">
                                    <div class="test-section"><a href="#"><img src="'.$Image .'" alt="">Testing</a>
                                    <p>checking data</p>
                                    </div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>',
                    'sort_order' => 0
                ];
                if (!$customBlock->getId()) {
                    $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($contentBlock )->save();
                } else {
                    $customBlock->setContent($contentBlock ['content'])->save();
                }
    }
  }
```

Here I have already block with same identifier and i am trying to update the content of it, I am getting below error.

> A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.

Am i used the correct code?  Can anyone help me to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Ref: https://webkul.com/blog/create-cms-block-installer-magento-2/ and this one also
https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-add-update-cms-static-block-via-install-upgrade-script-programmatically/

Comment: @RakeshDonga, this will create but update will not work here, is any issue in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are duplicate cms block available with different store. This error occurred from this file :

> vendor\magento\module-cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block.php

```
/**
 * Perform operations before object save
 *
 * @param AbstractModel $object
 * @return $this
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
{
    if (!$this->getIsUniqueBlockToStores($object)) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.')
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Debug in this function and check identifier and block id from this `$object`.

Comment: Yes there was a duplicate cms block associated with different store,@Rohan

Answer (score 1):

Set Block Id when you update the content.

```
if (!$customBlock->getId()) {

     $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($contentBlock )->save();
} else {
     $customBlock->setId($customBlock->getId())->setContent($contentBlock ['content'])->save();
}
```

Hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: or just use addData instead of setData to get rid of if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try out this module https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-simpledata which simplifies the process a lot.
It provides a simple API to create/modify/delete static blocks, pages.

Creating a block becomes then:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace MarkShust\Data\Setup\Patch\Data;

use MarkShust\SimpleData\Setup\Patch\SimpleDataPatch;

class BlockFooBarCreate extends SimpleDataPatch
{
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->block->save([
            'identifier' => 'foo_bar',
            'title' => 'Foo bar',
            'content' => <<<CONTENT
<div class="foo-bar">
    Foo bar
</div>
CONTENT,
        ]);
    }
}
```